# Trouble creating a closed line chart in svg

Tags: svg, linechart

I've got a react component which is creating an svg line chart (I'm not using a library, just creating the svg itself).

Problem is, when I add a final point to the path to return to the starting point, I have a strange 45degree angle showing up at the end of the chart.

Can anybody explain why this is not nicely closed?

Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/7svavrmu/1/

From what I understand, the final `L 0 300` should be returning the path to the origin.

Here's the code

```
<svg width="300" height="67.40652464075235">
  <path fill="blue" stroke="black" 
d="M 0 40.32613081539207
L 0.15306122448979592 40.990776224724726 
L 0.25510204081632654 41.834373941621585 
L 0.30612244897959184 62.31225269212592 
L 299.0816326530612 45.84534164491692 
L 299.33673469387753 65.256033885832 
L 299.48979591836735 45.314084715607414 
L 300 45.27080004137377 L 0 300 "></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: The easiest way to close a path is to use z or Z

Comment: It is not clear how the chart would be displayed, but you surely mean `L 300 0` and not `L 0 300`. First number is `x`, second is `y`.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure what you are saying, can you clarify?

Comment: @Duopixel reversing to `L 300 0` is not correct, but you lead me to something interesting. https://jsfiddle.net/7svavrmu/2/ - if the last entry goes to the final point at `300 67` then I include `L 0 300` it completes properly, though I'm not sure I completely understand what's happening.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG paths, each letter is an instruction and the following numbers are the coordinates for that instruction.

Your path ends at a strange location, `L 0 300` is the bottom left location but way off the viewport, you need to "draw" the bottom part of your graph by removing the last instruction and adding `L 300 67` (bottom right corner) and `L 0 67` (bottom left corner). Putting it all together your path needs to look like this:

```
d="M 0 40.32613081539207
L 0.15306122448979592 40.990776224724726 
L 0.25510204081632654 41.834373941621585 
L 0.30612244897959184 62.31225269212592 
L 299.0816326530612 45.84534164491692 
L 299.33673469387753 65.256033885832 
L 299.48979591836735 45.314084715607414 
L 300 45.27080004137377 L 300 67 L 0 67"
```

Comment: Now I see, thanks for clarifing. So basically what I have to do is put the last point to the 2nd end point of the svg `L 300 67` and the last point at the bottom start `L 0 67` thank you for clarifying.